# Zip file is empty exception while starting hybris server with cybersource integration but only from office

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, cybersource

I am having a very weird issue where I am getting below error when I try to start hybris server with cybersource integration from office but when I start the server from home it starts without any issues. I am also not getting this issue from office when I use mobile hotspot.

```
WARN  [localhost-startStop-5] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abcintegrationService' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'abcCyberSource' while setting bean property 'abcCyberSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abcCyberSource' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionProcessor' while setting bean property 'transactionProcessor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionProcessor' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cybersource.schemas.transaction_data.transactionprocessor.TransactionProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
ERROR [localhost-startStop-5] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abcintegrationService' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'abcCyberSource' while setting bean property 'abcCyberSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abcCyberSource' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionProcessor' while setting bean property 'transactionProcessor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionProcessor' defined in class path resource [abcintegration-spring.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cybersource.schemas.transaction_data.transactionprocessor.TransactionProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
```

Cybersource giving issue from office network.

Also this error started showing up when we migrated to sap commerce version 2211.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an issue with the office network. since you mentioned the app works at home and using mobile hotspot. See if you can show DEBUG level logs or try to check with your Network/Infrastructure team if something is getting blocked.